# How to parse textarea and select with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have some code which parses via jsoup the input fields on a webpage. After completing the code I found my form also has some textarea fields and dropdown

```
<textarea name='asr_remarks'class='inputbox-highlighted-false'cols=70 rows=3 
onKeyPress="LimitRemark(this);" >This is a test remark for info only</textarea>
```

As well as my select box, how can I retrieve the name and the value selected ?

```
<select name="supp" class="textbox"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1 - Cancel</option>
<option value="2">2 - Due Date Change</option>
<option value="3">3 - Change after FOC</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">4 - Change before FOC</option></select>
```

Comment: Could you please also show your java code (only the relevant part, that is)

Comment: Why is this question tagged javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Refer http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

For textarea:

```
Element t = doc.select("textarea[name=asr_remarks]").first();
String t_val = t.html();
```

For getting selected value of a select box:

```
Element opt = doc.select("select[name=supp]").first().select("option[selected]").first();
int opt_value = Integer.parseInt(opt.attr('value'));
String opt_text = opt.html();
```

Comment: ok, I played around a bit and it seems to work fine, the only issue I am having is that if the area is not found its not defined and it throws an error. How can I check to make sure there is actual a section before I try to assign it.

    asrRmk  = asrRmk.select("textarea[name=asr_remarks]").first();

    if (asrRmk  != "undefined") {
    asrRmk  = asrRmk .html();
  
          data = { name="asr_remarks"
            , value=asrRmk 
            , type="textarea"
            };

  // store in array
         arrayAppend(yourArray, data);
    
         }

Comment: Yeah that will happen. You should use if null check to make sure the element exists if there is a chance the html might not contain the element. Same goes for the select box too.